# Doctrine 2 wont search for accent letters when parameter is binded

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

searched keyword is **adác** and the original query:

```
->getConnection()->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM x WHERE word LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"');
```

is fine, but SQL hacky. With this:

```
->getConnection()->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM x WHERE word LIKE "%?0%"')->setParameters([$keyword]);
```

wont find anything, parameter becames **ad\u00e1c**. Why?

Comment: What is your database collation?I am using utf8_unicode_ci and I don't find such issue with accented caraters. And is Not using DQL or QueryBuilder a requirement?

Comment: `$theString=   "adác";
     $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT m
                FROM MembersManagementBundle:ProfilePhoto m               
                WHERE m.word=:wd
                ')->setParameters(array ('wd' => $theString)); $n = $query->getResult();`

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers there are other criterias which cannot be written with QueryBuilder

Comment: I agree regarding QueryBuilder, but i think DQL (as in example ) or NativeQuery at max will help you use raw sql with the features of doctrine. anyways, what about charset?  `doctrine:
    dbal:
        charset: utf8mb4`